# Return an array of adresses

Tags: solidity, mapping

I have a mapping with the key as an address and the value as  an array of addresses. How do I return the array of addresses? In older solidity versions it works. In newer compiler versions I have to declare memory. Is this producing the problem in my example? Is there a workaround for? Here is a code snippet:

```
mapping(address => address[]) wallets;

    function getWallets(address _user) 
        public
        view
        returns(address[] memory)
    {
        return wallets[_user];
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. What problem are you having?